# Wildcard for angular 2 router not working properly

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

If I enter URL structured like localhost:3000/something the app is correctly redirected to localhost:3000/login, but if I enter URL in form of localhost:3000/something/something the app crashes because the router doesn't redirect correctly.

I set router file like this:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
      { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
    ])
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

I'm using HTML5 URL style In my Angular 2 application.

How can I set wildcard to show user 404 page when he enters work when he enters URL like localhost:3000/something/something?

Comment: is there any error you are getting ?

Comment: And if us use ''/**"

Comment: @ranakrunal9 yes, there are some errors, but only errors that app cant find js and css resources: `GET http://localhost:3000/prva/css/style.css 
dsad:13 GET http://localhost:3000/prva/css/bootstrap.css 
dsad:18 GET http://localhost:3000/prva/css/iskalnik.css ...`

@KwintenP if I use "/**" I get error saying `Invalid route configuration of route '/**': path cannot start with a slash `

Comment: In my [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/DI1Rydk1mBYKUso2E75z?p=preview) it works. What are the errors?

Comment: @FabrizioDeBortoli this works fine for me too. The problem occures if I type url (url as I mentioned in my question) in browser url bar not in app.